# visual studio / typescript typings errors

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, tsconfig

While reading .js files on 'dist' folders, I keep getting errors "Cannot find name 'require' ts 2304", "Cannot find name 'exports' ts 2304" and "Cannot find name 'process' ts 2580". I already tried `npm install @types/node --save-dev` but nothing changed, even after restarting vscode. Already recreated node_modules and yarn.lock by removing it and running yarn install. What else can I try ?

tsconfig.json:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2015"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["node"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

npm ls:

```
├── @mikro-orm/cli@5.3.1
├── @mikro-orm/core@5.3.1
├── @mikro-orm/postgresql@5.3.1
├── @types/node@18.7.11
├── @types/uuid@8.3.4
├── class-validator@0.13.2
├── dotenv@16.0.1
├── esm@3.2.25
├── graphql@16.6.0
├── reflect-metadata@0.1.13
├── ts-node@10.9.1
├── type-graphql@1.1.1
├── typedi@0.10.0
└── uuid@8.3.2
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mikro-orm/core": "^5.3.1",
    "@mikro-orm/postgresql": "^5.3.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
    "typedi": "^0.10.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mikro-orm/cli": "^5.3.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.11",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "mikro-orm": {
    "useTsNode": true,
    "configPaths": [
      "./src/mikro-orm.config.ts",
      "./dist/mikro-orm.config.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Here what I found:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling

answer is: "Under the covers, we run the TypeScript compiler as a task. The command we use is: tsc -p ."

I run tsc -p . and errors are gone.